# What am I doing wrong in the code , for submitting form values to MySQL via Flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to generate random codes considering the form inputs, like the number of the random codes the user wants to generate. And then add those data into MySQL Table.

Here is the HTML:

```
<HTML>
<BODY bgcolor="cyan">
<form method="POST" action="">
    <center>
    <H1>Enter your details </H1> <br>
    Code-Attribute (eg. itsa19) <input type = "text" name= "code_attribute" /> <br>
    Max Usage <input type = "number" name = "max_usage" /> <br>
    Max No of Users <input type = "number" name = "users" /> <br>
    Data Volume (in GB) <input type = "number" name = "data_volume" /> <br>
    How many codes you want to create? <input type = "number" name = "number_of_codes" /> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload code in Database">
    </center>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The flask app will get those data, and appends random code to the code-attribute. Then it executes cursor to insert data into the table.

Here is the flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MY_DB'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":  // Gets the form inputs
        details = request.form
        AttributeCode = details['code_attribute']
        MaxUsage = details['max_usage']
        NumberOfUsers= details['users']
        UsageVol = details['data_volume']  
        NumberOfCodes = details['number_of_codes']

    import string 
    import random

    def random_numbers():    // Generate Random Codes (Column 1)
            N = 7
            res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase +
                             string.digits, k = N)) 

            prefix = AttributeCode
            DiscountCode = prefix + res
            columns = [MaxUsage, NumberOfUsers, UsageVol]
            randoms.append(DiscountCode)     // appends column values
            randoms.extend(columns)   
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO discount_codes(codes, max_usage, users, data_volume) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (randoms[0],randoms[1],randoms[2],randoms[3]))  # I have also tried puting ('TestCode', 2 ,3 ,4)
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()

        for _ in range(NumberOfCodes):
            random_numbers()   
        return 'success'

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Kindly help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It works, just a small mistake. NumberOfCodes was in str instead of an int value.

Comment: That indentation looks wrong. It shows `random_numbers()` calling itself, but not being called otherwise.